# Transforming a json column to new json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgres table in which I have a column called data like this:

```
data
{'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c':[32,55]}
{'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c':[20,30,50]}
...
...
```

I want to get a new column from it, with a new json containing only 'a' and 'c'.

Desired output:

```
{'a': 3, 'c':[32,55]}
{'a': 5, 'c':[20,30,50]}
```

I tried to use #>, but I didnt really get the online documentation
Here is the attempt to select {'a': 3}, but I only get 3

```
SELECT
    id
    , data#> '{a}' as data
FROM raw_daily_service.programuser
```

Comment: why is it array is not closed? `:[32`? with bracket

Comment: sorry Its a mistake. I modify it

Comment: do you have initial query, what you tried so far?

Comment: I edited the code with the query I tried, so select one {key: value}. The goal remains to select 2 of the atttributes

Comment: Can you post your desired output?  Do you want to return `a` and `c` as their own separate columns?  Or do you want to transform to a differently formatted `json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your trying achieve.Here's the complete list of [json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) functions and operators.

We need to rebuild your object using `json_build_object()` after `json_each_text()`

```
 SELECT id, json_build_object(key,value)
 FROM raw_daily_service.programuser t
 JOIN json_each_text(t.data) d ON true
 WHERE key in ('a', 'c')
```

Comment: This gives the  value, while what I want is a json with both the attribute and the value {attribute: value}.
Also, what I want is both 'a' and 'c' in the same JSON

Comment: well, you need to include your desired output

Comment: We need to rebuild your object using json_build_object() after json_each_text(), try this one